# Deploy Python Flexible App Engine without entrypoint and just cron jobs

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to use app engine to run several scripts at set intervals using cron jobs that update a directory I am serving to urls. I am able to serve the directories with a handler in app.yaml but standard environment did not allow me to use all the libraries I needed so I switched to flexible environment. Now, my problem is I need an entrypoint but as my objective is just to have a server that does nothing except execute cron jobs, how would I implement this in the flexible environment?

Answer (score 2):

The GAE cron service is just a generator of scheduled GET requests for particular urls (in both standard and flexible environments). From [Scheduling Jobs with **cron.yaml**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml):

> A cron job will invoke a URL, using an HTTP GET request, at a given
>   time of day. An HTTP request invoked by cron can run for up to 60
>   minutes, but is [subject to the same limits as other HTTP
>   requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/how-requests-are-handled#quotas_and_limits).

The actual cron jobs are just (regular) app handlers for those particular GET requests. You still need to write those handlers, just like any other handlers for any other request some other app might need.

The app code with your handlers will be your entrypoint, nothing special about it just because the app's not doing anything else beside cron jobs.

Comment: That worked in standard environment but flexible environment requires something in the entrypoint field of app.yaml or it will not let me deploy. Would I have to put one of the cron job handlers I have in the entrypoint field?

Comment: So the entrypoint would just run a particular GET request once on deployment right unlike cron jobs which schedule them to run at set intervals?

Comment: By entrypoint do you mean something else than the `app.yaml`' s `entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app` (or equivalent)? If so please define it.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. It looks like the flexible environment requires it for deployment, so if I put a python script in that line, would It just run the script once on deployment and then do nothing?

Comment: The app is not a standalone python script, it's **a web app** which knows how to answer to http(s) requests (in your case those cron requests). But it's still a web app. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart#hello_world_code_review